# How can I track Access crashes

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I was asked to add a new button on a couple DB forms.  The button changes the queue that the record is in, and then closes the form.  Nothing fancy.  I have the same button with the same code on three different forms.  On 2 of those forms, it works just as I'd expect.

The button works fine every other time on the last form, and crashes Access on the other tries.  I've tried adding error logging, but it crashes prior to anything being logged.  I've stepped through the code and it crashes at `rs.Edit` in the below code...

Code on the form behind the click event of the button: (each form has this behind the button)

```
Private Sub bRtD_Click()

  LogReturnToDashboard Me.Recordset

  DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo

End Sub
```

Called Function: (error handler removed since it isn't being triggered anyway, and to keep an already long post shorter)

```
Public Function LogReturnToDashboard(ByRef rs As DAO.Recordset)
Dim sSQL As String
Dim lLoc As Long

'Get Dashboard
  lLoc = GetDashboard(rs!Role)

  sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblActivity ( Vendor, FromLocation, OldStatus, ToLocation ) " & _
         "VALUES (" & rs!VID & ", " & rs!Location & ", " & rs!Status & ", " & lLoc & ");"
  CurrentDb.Execute (sSQL)

  rs.Edit    <-------- This is where it crashes
  rs!Location = lLoc
  rs.Update

End Function
```

The SQL command executes, I can check `tblActivity` and see the line with the record being changed back to the dashboard.

Google-fu seems to return issues with ADODB recordsets crashing Access, but not DAO.

And why would it literally work every other time?  I'm at a loss.  I clearly can't publish this when it crashes this consistently.

I checked the AppLog and found this entry, but this doesn't tell me much.  This seems to be a generic error for the Office Suite as Google returns pages that declare the problem is every piece of the suite.

[image: Access Error]

Any ideas?  Just having a better idea of where to look would be great, I've searched every part of the error log, and nothing seems specific to Access.

**UPDATE:**
So far I have:
 - Created a new DB and imported everything....reset references...etc
 - Created brand new forms and copied all content.
 - Decompiled the DB
 - Stepped through code behind buttons that seem to crash more often than others...Did NOT find that they crash in similar parts.  (I now have other buttons that are causing Access to crash besides the original one here...none of the others crash at `rs.edit` btw)
 - Downloaded a different version of acedao.dll
 - Posted on the MS site hoping to get more answers...

So far, I still can't seem to make any progress on preventing these crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to stop the crashes!!

For some reason, Access was occasionally throwing a hissy fit over the passing of the recordset to a module.

It worked fine (meaning as intended and no crashes) for weeks...then suddenly started crashing.  And it didn't crash consistently either.  One button was very consistent in that it would work one time, then crash the next...then work the next time, and crash the time after that.

I've started passing the PK for the form's record instead and then in the module creating a recordset filtered by the passed value.  I have been able to work with no crashes since then.

Thanks for the options guys...I clearly whittled out some junk that didn't need to be included by the decompile and using a new DB shell.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are experiencing unexplained crashes with code that works in other forms in your Access database, you most likely have a "slightly" corrupt form in your database.  I would recommend trying to `decompile` the database file.

You can get more information about the `/decompile` switch from the following:

[How to Decompile a Database](http://datagnostics.com/dtips/decompile.html)

[Decompile Your Microsoft Access Database](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/errors/Bad_DLL_Calling_Convention.asp)

I would make a backup copy of the database, then do a decompile, and then a compact.  Then open up the database and open your VBA Editor and Compile your code.  Then test it.

The `/decompile` switch has fixed many strange problems with Microsoft Access databases for me in the past.

Regarding your desire to log or track more details on the cause of the crash, unfortunately there is no way to do so.  VBA in Microsoft Access provides no way to intercept errors or crashes in the Microsoft Access executable itself.

Give `/decompile` a try.

Comment: I've tried this 3 times now...still crashes.  So I'm guessing that it isn't my VBA that's the problem.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a new empty database file and importing all of your objects (tables/queries/forms/etc) from the old file?  If you have a split database, also create a new file for the data and import everything.  Sometimes importing all of your objects into a new file is the only way to remove or uncover the corrupt object.  There is nothing wrong with your VBA code, I still think the problem is some sort of damage to an object in your database.

Comment: I'll try that when I get a chance.

Comment: Sadly, still crashes.  However, the size did drop like 300k and change...so something got left out.  But it still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a record to edit.
Think about what record you are on.

Comment: No, the record stays the same.  It simply changes on field in the record.  Definitely not an EOF issue.

Comment: It's not EOF, I don't think Access knows what record you are on. But to be sure, we need more info. Like the forms and tables involved.

Comment: If that were true, why would it work fine on 2 other forms, and half the time on the exact same record?  The recordset is passed in and at the `rs.edit` command it crashes...no change in the record at all up to that point.  If Access doesn't know what record it is supposed to be on...how do forms and functions ever work??  I'm trying to understand how this might be the issue...